# UIAutomatorViewer In mac

Tags: java, junit, appium

I am trying to run UIAutomatorViewer on my mac, but the command is not recognized follows my defined environment variables:

```
export ANDROID_HOME = / Users / jribeiro / Library / Android / sdk

export PATH = $ {PATH}: $ {ANDROID_HOME} / emulator
export PATH = $ {PATH}: $ {ANDROID_HOME} / tools
export PATH = $ {PATH}: $ {ANDROID_HOME} / tools / bin
export PATH = $ {PATH}: $ {ANDROID_HOME} / platform-tools


export JAVA_HOME = / Library / Java / JavaVirtualMachines / jdk1.8.0_261.jdk / Contents / Ho $
export PATH = $ {PATH}: $ JAVA_HOME / bin
export PATH = ~ / Library / Android / sdk / platform-tools: / usr / local / bin: / usr / bin: / bin: / $
```

can someone help me to call the UIAutomatorView ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the appium desktop app > Start server > click on search icon on the app > UI automator view is opened.
2. You can first check your uiautomatorviewer.bat at `Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/` and can start the same by executing `Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/uiautomatorviewer`.

Comment: uiautomatorviewer.bat will not work on Mac, it is Windows script

Comment: And there is no Library/Android directory on a Mac